# How to check if SQLDataReader item is DateTime os String type value?

Tags: sql, vb.net, csv, datareader

I have a function that converts datareader to CSV. SQL return **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000** while .net converts it to **MM/DD/YYYY** value.
I would like to check if the value in the datareader is DateTime and convert it back to **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000** format.

UPDATE:

Code:

```
Public Function DR_To_CSV_Stream() As Boolean
    Dim FirstLine As String = ""
    Dim retVal As Boolean

    m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "DR_To_CSV_Stream: "

    If m_Datareader.Read Then 'CREATE HEADER NAMES
        m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "CREATE HEADER NAMES: "
        For intcount = 0 To m_Datareader.FieldCount - 1
            If intcount <> m_Datareader.FieldCount - 1 Then
                sw.Write(String.Format("""{0}"",", m_Datareader.GetName(intcount)))
                FirstLine = FirstLine + String.Format("""{0}"",", m_Datareader.Item(intcount))
            Else
                sw.Write(String.Format("""{0}""", m_Datareader.GetName(intcount)))
                FirstLine = FirstLine + String.Format("""{0}""", m_Datareader.Item(intcount))
            End If
        Next
        sw.WriteLine("")
        m_DebugMessage = String.Format("{0}WriteLine(FirstLine): {1}", m_DebugMessage, FirstLine)
        sw.WriteLine(FirstLine)

        Do While m_Datareader.Read() 'READ DATA AND CREATE ROWS
            m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "READ DATA AND CREATE ROWS: "
            For intcount = 0 To m_Datareader.FieldCount - 1
                If intcount <> m_Datareader.FieldCount - 1 Then
                    sw.Write(String.Format("""{0}"",", m_Datareader.Item(intcount)))
                Else
                    sw.Write(String.Format("""{0}""", m_Datareader.Item(intcount)))
                End If
            Next
            sw.WriteLine("")
        Loop
        m_Datareader.Close()
        m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "m_Datareader.Close(): "
        m_Datareader = Nothing
    Else
        m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "m_Datareader.Read = FALSE: "
    End If
    sw.Flush() 'COMMIT LAST SECTION TO WRITER
    If sw.BaseStream Is Nothing Then
        m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "  |  |NOTHING IN THE STREAM: "
    Else
        m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "  |  |THERE IS SOMETHING IN THE STREAM: "
    End If


    m_sr = New IO.StreamReader(sw.BaseStream)
    m_sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    m_ReturnStream = m_sr.BaseStream

    If m_ReturnStream.CanRead Then
        retVal = True
        m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "  |  | 2ND TIME - THERE IS SOMETHING IN THE STREAM: "

    Else
        retVal = False
        m_DebugMessage = m_DebugMessage & "  |  |NOTHING IN THE RETURN STREAM: "
    End If



    Return retVal

End Function
```

This function converts datareader to CSV stream. In another function I convert this stream to string and write it to the File:

File.WriteAllBytes(outboundFileFullPath, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data))

Hope that helps to understand my issue.

Or another way would be: to write MemoryStream directly to the file. I tried that but didn't work.
Thanks!

UPDATE#2
Here's what I did based on Romil's suggestion:

```
   Dim dateValue As Date
                    If intcount <> m_Datareader.FieldCount - 1 Then
                        If (DateTime.TryParse(m_Datareader.Item(intcount).ToString(), dateValue)) Then
                            sw.Write(String.Format("""{0}"",", dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")))
                        Else
                            sw.Write(String.Format("""{0}"",", m_Datareader.Item(intcount)))
                        End If
                    Else
                        sw.Write(String.Format("""{0}""", m_Datareader.Item(intcount)))
                    End If
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: .NET doesn't "convert it" to "MM/DD/YYYY", although the *string representation* might look like that after a call to `ToString`. Now see if it is indeed now a string, and from where. Ref. [DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParse`

```
string input = "2000-02-02";
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out dateTime))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    }
```

[More Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparse)

Answer (score 0):

You can override default culture for the current thread to specify default DateTime format you want:

```
    Dim c As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)
    c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    c.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.fff"
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = c
```